Issues while rigging
I encountered issues while animating a custom Unity model after adding new bones and a meta rig. The hands and fingers were deforming or remaining in place even when moved. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?"

Have you applied Scale, Rotation, and Location to the meta rig before you generated the rig?

Kindly attach your blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
